# SQLiteException get which value was unique

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm trying to insert user into SQLite database. And i have two columns which are unique, those are username and email. When i try to insert user and table already contains that username or email it throws an error. When i catch the error and print message it says.

09-28 16:20:30.079 5249-5249/com.example.miljanrakita.shoppingapplication D/RegisterActivity: registerUser: UNIQUE constraint failed: users.email (code 2067)

This is the part i need users.email. Because if email already exist this is the message, if it was username it would be users.username, so that is how i am going to know which one of these already exists. Is there any chance to get only this party from exception ? I don't want to split strings or something like that or to have multiple select statements which will check if email or username already exists.

This is the addUser method.

```
@Override
public void addUser(User user) throws SQLiteException {
    mDatabase.insertOrThrow(UserTable.NAME, null, getContentValues(user));
}
```

and this is the method which class this method which will call addUser and handle exception

```
private boolean registerUser() {
    try {
        User user = new User(username, password, name, surname, address, email, phone);
        UserProvider.getSingleton(getApplicationContext()).getUserProvider().addUser(user);
    } catch (SQLiteException exception) {

        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You should probably use raw SQL

Comment: "_I don't want to split strings or something like that_" You mean you want to tell the difference between two different error messages, without examining the insides of those messages???

Comment: I meant when i get this error message : UNIQUE constraint failed: users.email i don't want to use String.split(" ") and loop until i get to users.email. I was wondering if there exists some way to get this message  users.email without splitting. I hope there is because that message will change depends on the Column which is unique. @TripeHound

Comment: Why does your app even allow submitting invalid values? You should have checked earlier.

Comment: `if( error.contains("users.email") ) { ... } else if( error.contains("users.user") ) {...}` perhaps? (Or check before insertion as CL says).

Comment: @TripeHound I know to do it like that also, i was just wondering if there is any built in chance to get it from the exception. Because it is stored somewhere as column name, so i thought if i can get it

Comment: I now realise what you mean. No: the core SQLite code (in 'C') just returns an error string. The wrapping of that in an Exception is down to the interface layer.

Comment: @TripeHound Thank you, it seems like i will need to go with splitting or contains. :)